# payloadfactory configuration for JSON request

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm trying for a post API (wso2 APIm v1.9), requirement is to pass dynamic application/xml payload to back-end service url.

I'm passing json payload from the API console and from api synapse configuration then using PayloadFactory mediator, i have created dynamic payload which will be pass to service endpoint.

PayloadFactory configuration appended with  and  tags:

```
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <input>
                           <Param>$1</Param>
                        </input>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg evaluator="json" expression="$."/> //passing like this since the json payload is massive.      
                     </args>
      </payloadFactory>
```

While testing API, getting below error
API console Response:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
  <am:code>404</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Production key offered to the API with no production endpoint</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

Can you please check and suggest what is the issue with my configuration.

API config:

```
<resource methods="POST"
                uri-template="/sample/{id}/sub"
                faultSequence="fault">
         <inSequence>
            <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
               <then>
                  <property name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"
                            expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"/>
                  <property name="Authorization"
                            expression="fn:concat('Basic ', 'dXNlcjp1c2Vy')"
                            scope="transport"/>
                  <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <input>
                           <newParam>$1</newParam>
                        </input>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg evaluator="json" expression="$."/>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint name="admin--Test_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                        <http uri-template="http://xxxx:8181/ValidateWAR/getValidate/validate"/>
                        <property name="Content-Type" value="application/xml" scope="transport"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </then>
               <else>
                  <sequence key="_sandbox_key_error_"/>
               </else>
            </filter>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
      </resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should develop the logic inside an API defined in the wso2 ESB. The processing should occur there , while the API Manager is there to 'manage' your back-end API service. This is known as the API Facade pattern (http://wso2.com/blogs/architecture/2013/05/a-pragmatic-approach-to-the-api-faade-pattern/).

You should not tinker with the Synapse source view in the API Manager , as it is auto-generated and carefully developed by wso2 guys.

Once you have your esb api then call that api from the API Manager ( by pointing to it as the production endpoint , in the publisher)